# Identify unknown word (Word not inside of HashMap Dictionary)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Is there a way to identify if a user put in a word that is not in your hashmap dictionary? Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("dog", "type of animal");
```

If the user were to ask for the definition of "cat," is there a way to identify that the word does not have a definition? And, if so, how could I set it to where the user could add this definition? Like:

"Definition of cat."

 -Definition does not exist. Add definition:

"Type of animal."

And then when you would ask for the definition again, it would give that definition. I would have looked this up myself, but the search terms are too specific to find anything helpful.

Comment: map.keySet().contains("cat") returns true/false if there is/isn't an entry

Comment: `map.containsKey(input)`

Answer (score 0):

If the key doesn't exist in your map, it will return `null`

```
String definition = null;
if ((definition = map.get(input)) != null){
  return definition;
}else{
  //do your stuff. add to your map
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HashMap<String, String> map...`

Than you can use `map.containsKey(String)`

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it:

```
if (map.containsKey(input)){
  return map.get(input); //this is your definition
}else{
  //do your stuff.
}
```

So that way you avoid the null value from your code!

Comment: What would I set definition to?

Comment: I figure `getKey()` would be the method that I would use to get the definition, but all of my definitions are listed simply using `map.put();`. Could I set the key that it grabs to user-input?

Answer (score 0):

If you had spent 2 mins googling you would find that `containsKey` was designed on tyhat purpose.
It retaurns false if the key is not present.

You can also cheks if the `get` method returns null;

check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)!